# How to fix the error from ```from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_logging_ops``` library?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Below is the code snippet, where I want to build an image summary.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_logging_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as _ops

def build_image_summary():
    log_image_data = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, [None, None, 3])
    log_image_name = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
    log_image = gen_logging_ops._image_summary(log_image_name, tf.expand_dims(log_image_data, 0), max_images=1)    
    _ops.add_to_collection(_ops.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES, log_image)
    return log_image, log_image_data, log_image_name
```

But executing above code, I attribute error as below:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.gen_logging_ops' has no attribute '_image_summary'
```

I changed `gen_logging_ops._image_summary` to `gen_logging_ops.summary.image` but still i get new errors!. I am using tensorflow version 1.15.2. How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The tf_op_gen_wrapper_py bazel rule is the rule generating the gen_ files. As explained, in this answer, this rule generates all the python wrapper of the ops defined in this library:

```
py_library(
    name = "logging_ops",
    srcs = ["ops/logging_ops.py"],
    srcs_version = "PY2AND3",
    deps = [
        ":framework_for_generated_wrappers",
        ":logging_ops_gen",
        ":util",
    ],
)
```

In the logging_ops case there is an indirection: the call to tf_op_gen_wrapper_py is hidden in tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py:

```
 tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py(
    name = "logging_ops_gen",
    visibility = [
        "//learning/brain/python/ops:__pkg__",
        "//tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:__pkg__",
    ],
)
```

Comment: so is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Replace from `gen_logging_ops._image_summary` to `gen_logging_ops.image_summary`.
This solved my issue!